# SwiftUI: Correct syntax to add a custom Symbol image/SVG to a view?

Tags: swiftui

I've followed the documentation for making a symbol set here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

And also the docs on configuring: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/configuring_and_displaying_symbol_images_in_your_ui

However, nothing covers what the syntax is to actually include one of these in a view. For example, given a Symbol Image in Assets.xcassets called "sausages" what should the correct syntax be below, instead of `Image(systemName: "sausages")`, which just renders a blank space?

How does a symbolSet become a usable image? Is that the problem here?

```
Text("Sausages")  
    .font(.title)  
    .tabItem {  
        VStack {  
           Image(systemName: "sausages")  
           Text("sausages")  
        }  
    }
```

Or does this have to be done with standard Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `Image` from the traditional `UIImage(named` syntax

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "sausages")!)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! As a beginner to Swift as well as SwiftUI this piece of syntax had completely eluded me!

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
var body: some View {
   Image("example-image")
}
```

or to check:

```
guard let img = UIImage(named: "example-image") else {
   print("Unable to load image")
}

return Image(UIImage: img)
```

[image]

Comment: The first example you provided is where I started but unfortunately nothing rendered. Taking the approach given by the accepted answer made it work as expected.

Comment: @BenFrain which version of XCode do you use? SwiftUI is constantly changing. I'm using Xcode 11.1 GM seed Build 11A1027

Comment: I'm on 11.0. Will try the simpler syntax again when I have updated.

Comment: just tried with 11.1 but same problem, need to use syntax from accepted answer.

Comment: is the name  the same of the image in Assets.xcassets? See image attached, it's works!

Comment: Both syntaxes are valid. This is shorter. Even for the colors it is the same. `.foregroundColor(Color("Purple"))` or `.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "Purple")!))` and obviously the same name of the assets in Assets.xcassets

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Johannes answer, which is the syntax I use with Xcode Version 11.2.1, you can also add styles like this;

```
Image("my.custom.symbol")
.font(Font.system(size: 24, weight: .light))
.foregroundColor(Color("myCustomColor"))
```